# doctrine 2 query builder count one to many relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have the following query:

```
  $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('shoppingcart')
            ->from("AppMainBundle:ShoppingCart", 'shoppingcart')
            ->innerJoin('shoppingcart.shoppingCartProducts', 'shoppingcartproduct')
            ->innerJoin('shoppingcartproduct.product', 'product')
            ->innerJoin('shoppingcartproduct.productAttribute', 'productattribute')
            ->innerJoin('product.shop', 'shop')
            ;
```

how do I write a where statement, where I only want to get shoppingcart that has more than one shoppingcartproduct in it? Here's the relationship of shopping cart and shoppingcart product:

```
class ShoppingCart
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShoppingCartProduct", mappedBy="shoppingCart", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    protected $shoppingCartProducts;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add following lines

```
->addSelect('COUNT(shoppingcartproduct) as nProducts')
->addGroupBy('shoppingcart.id')
->having('nProducts > 1')
```

Comment: How can I access "nProducts" from result of query? here I use getResult() on query object.

Comment: $result[0] will be Shoppingcart, $result['nProducts'] = 123;

Comment: In case the query should return an array of objects and the actual number of products does not matter, the select clause should be `COUNT(shoppingcardproduct) AS HIDDEN nProducts`.